# RasPi 4 -> WiFi Access Point?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4, access-point

I have been trying to set up my RasPi 4 as an WiFi access point, but with no success.

however, the guides I have been using were written for RasPi 3:

- [thepi.io](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/)
- [sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all)

I'll follow the guides, but when it comes time to check for the network using another device - the network name does not appear in the list of available WiFi networks.

I was wondering if there was something about the RasPi 4 that meant that those guides would be obsolete?

many thanks,

Comment: Maybe you can explain why so many people seem to find tutorials for obsolete OS but not the official Foundation guides.

Comment: Everything about those guides is obsolete. They aren't based on Raspbian Buster. They aren't up to date for the RPi4B. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: Google gave me those guides before the official ones.  Maybe the official documentation could do with some SEO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the Raspberry Pi foundations access point tutorial successfully on my Pi4.

Edit: (new link)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

(old link)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: yes this works - many thanks CoderMike !!

Comment: As of today the link returns a 404 not found

Comment: Updated new link

Answer (score 3):

You could also try this tutorial:
Start with a clean install of the latest release of Raspbian (currently Buster). Raspbian Buster Lite is recommended.

Update Raspbian, including the kernel and firmware, followed by a reboot:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Set the WiFi country in raspi-config’s Localisation Options: sudo raspi-config

If you have an older Raspberry Pi without an onboard WiFi chipset, the Edimax Wireless 802.11b/g/n nano USB adapter is an excellent option – it’s small, cheap and has good driver support.
With the prerequisites done, you can proceed with either the Quick installer or Manual installation steps below.

Quick installer

Install RaspAP from your RaspberryPi’s shell prompt:

```
curl -sL https://install.raspap.com | bash
```

The installer will complete the steps in the manual installation (below) for you.

After the reboot at the end of the installation the wireless network will be configured as an access point as follows:

```
IP address: 10.3.141.1
Username: admin
Password: secret
DHCP range: 10.3.141.50 to 10.3.141.255
SSID: raspi-webgui
Password: ChangeMe
```

**Note:** As the name suggests, the Quick Installer is a great way to quickly setup a new AP. However, it does not automagically detect the unique configuration of your RPi. Best results are obtained by connecting an RPi to ethernet (eth0) or as a WiFi client, also known as managed mode, with wlan0. For the latter, refer to this FAQ. Please read this before reporting an issue.

**Simultaneous AP and Wifi client**

RaspAP lets you easily create an AP with a Wifi client configuration. With your RPi configured in managed mode, enable the AP from the Advanced tab of Configure hotspot by sliding the Wifi client AP mode toggle. Save settings and start the hotspot. The managed mode AP is functional without restart.

**Note:** For a Raspberry Pi operating in managed mode without an eth0 connection, this configuration must be enabled before a reboot.

https://raspap.com/